# Can't load nib when nib name ends with number

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nib

I have created another nib file for iPhone 5 (one view controller). I have named it MainScreeniPhone5.
but strange behavior is that app cant load this nib file when running on retina 4 simulator!! 
if I remove "5" at the end of nib it loads the nib.

I have also added it to "bundle resources"

why this happens? does nib files cant have numbers at end of their names?

Comment: If you remove "5", does your app run on other iPhone emulators??

Comment: I think that was because of simulator. on other emulators it works well!